# Daily logRotate for apache at specific time

Tags: debian, cron, logs, apache-httpd, logrotate

How can I execute logRotate daily at a specific time (3h30) each day? Specific details on how to do this would be appreciated.

I'm on Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step #1 - create script

You can create a file such as this:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/cron.d/logrotate
```

And add these lines to this file:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

#### Step #2 - add script to crontab file

Then create a crontab entry that runs this script at 3h30 each day. To do this 2nd step edit the file `/etc/crontab`:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/crontab
```

And add this line:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
30 3 * * *  root    /etc/cron.d/logrotate
```

**NOTE:** You might need to omit the user in some situations, like this:

```
# m h dom mon dow   command
30 3 * * *      /etc/cron.d/logrotate
```

#### Step #3 - make script executable

Lastly make the `logrotate` shell script (`/etc/cron.d/logrotate`) executable:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.d/logrotate
```

#### References

- [HowTo: The Ultimate Logrotate Command Tutorial with 10 Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/#more-4826)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have set up the scripts and I am waiting to see if it works, hope so.

Comment: I had to remove the root login in order to make it work.

Comment: @AbdelilahBenaou - did you change it to something else or completely delete it? LMK so I can update the A.

Comment: I changed the cron job line which goes like this :

Before :
30 3 * * *  root    /etc/cron.d/logrotate

After :
30 3 * * *  /etc/cron.d/logrotate

Comment: @AbdelilahBenaou - thanks I've added an example like this and a note.